# TextView disipado

Tags: android

Hola a todos tengo una duda como puedo hacer que la parte final de mi textView se muestre disipado o con algo de transparencia por ejemplo a mi textView lo meto un texto que es largo y mi textView tiene un tamaño fijo que yo lo puse y quisiera que en vez de que me lo corte mi texto al final me muestre como disipado o con algo de transparencia como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Prueba  solapar una capa encima con un canal alpha de degradado, vengo del el mundo CSS y supongo que aquí también serviría.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen varias formas la más común es aplicar una transparencia al color del texto:

```
    TextView miTextView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.miTextView);
    int myAlpha = 0; // 0 Transparente ,  255 completamente opaco.
    miTextView.setTextColor(Color.argb(myAlpha, 0, 255, 0)); //Texto color verde.
```

También se puede aplicar directamente la propiedad `android:alpha` al widget:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/miTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:text="Hola StackOverflow.com"
    android:alpha = ".50"/>
```

Si definimos un alpha de 0 el texto se ve completamente transparente, si definimos un alpha de 100:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si definimos un alpha de 255, se vería completamente opaco.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Si deseas aplicar transparencia a parte del texto, se puede realizar con un SpannableString :

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
SpannableStringBuilder spannablecontent = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hola StackOverflow!");

int myAlpha = 10; // 0 Transparente ,  255 completamente opaco.
ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.argb(myAlpha, 0, 0, 0)); // Color del texto Negro con alpha de 10 %

final StyleSpan bss = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

// Aplica el color definido, texto Negro con alpha de 10 %, a los primeros 4 caracteres.
spannablecontent.setSpan(fcs, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
spannablecontent.setSpan(bss, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

myTextView.setText(spannablecontent);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola @Elenasys, si funciona pero mi duda es como pondría esa transparencia a las dos ultimas letras o caracteres que aparecen dentro el textView

Answer (score 1):

Haciendo uso de *alpha* y añadiendo la propiedad de *textStyle* a tu TextView
Tienes dos formas:

**XML**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:alpha = ".3"
    android:textStyle="normal|italic"
    android:id="@+id/high_Score"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

**PROGRAMÁTICAMENTE**

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC); // O Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC si quieres en negrita.
```

Para la transparencia:

```
int alpha = 0;
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1)).setTextColor(Color.argb(alpha, 255, 0, 0));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo es un texto, puedes utilizar html y, mediante la asignación de colores con transparencia, hacerlo a mano. 
Por ejemplo, este texto:

```
String texto = "<font color=#cc0029>Ahora sin transparencia</font> <font color=#99000000>Ahora con transparencia</font>";

 mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(texto));
```

De todos modos, si lo haces de esta manera, un degradado a transparente tan progresivo con el de tu imagen será tedioso. Te lo pongo aún así por si te sirve.